# Roadtripping from NYC to Boulder, CO - sites to see along the way?

Tags: driving, road-trips

I am driving from NYC to Boulder, CO and have about 4-5 days to do the 27ish hour drive. Which route has more attractions along the lines of this list?

- natural sites, parks, features
- museums, breweries
- other famous spots I don't know about

I have two paths to take it seems, `Route 80`, the north route, and `Route 70`, the south route.

[image]

Comment: @pnuts it doesn't appear a conclusion was reached with that debate. This is a pretty common drive and thought someone may have done it who could easily offer some ideas. A travel agent is someone who I'd pay to book hotels, dining, and find specific sites. I'm handling room and board and the actual path of travel. This is not that question.

Comment: @pnuts Somewhat broad, but also quite helpful to anyone else down the line who has a similar trip. Opinions are helpful, but my question is moreso asking for enlightenment on things along those routes that fall into the buckets I've specified, which is more objective.

Comment: I'm afraid, but this Q should be closed for WANTA (which is a close-reason by itself so a conclusion was reached), too broad and primarily opinion-based. However see e.g. [What is a good way to get list of sights for a road trip (e.g. for a roadtrip from Chicago to Niagara falls?)](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/26432/32134)

Comment: @pnuts never heard of `geocaching` but this is the sort of stuff I was looking for! Really cool. Thanks guys

Comment: I had to vote to close it for the reasons given, but I will say that I've driven nearly every mile of both those routes and I'd choose I-80 every time. You'll barely be out of New Jersey before you start hitting stuff you listed, such as [Delaware Water Gap](https://www.nps.gov/dewa/). Stop in the [Amana Colonies](http://www.amanacolonies.com/) in Iowa for good food and beer and a very unique community worth a look. And keep your eyes open.

Comment: Finally, brown or blue highway signs will list attractions of the sort that you appear to be looking for. So that's what you want to keep your eyes open for.

Comment: Actually if you edit this Q to sth like 'which route has more attractions' instead of focusing on recommending single places it might be fit for reopening.

Comment: @mts done see above